# How to redirect absolute URL?

Tags: networking

At work, typing in

```
//sharepoint
```

as the URL in a browser takes me to a website.

I want to achieve this on my home network as well, how do I this? What is this even called?

E.g. redirecting //hue to 192.168.45.2 so I can control my lightbulbs.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at file on your local system when you type in the "//" in the url. There is no way to make this possible to spread through out your network unless you hosted some kind of server, and in that case, you would have to give them your internal IP as // would not work for them, it would just bring them to a file of their own.